# How to customize autocomplete listing view using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete jquery UI and autocomplete is working fine.

But Now i want to customize listing view(like: when i press **j** in textbox related data from j keyword will show customized div container).

Code what i have done :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var projects = [{
       value: "jquery",
       label: "jQuery",
       desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library"
   }, {
       value: "jquery-ui",
       label: "jQuery UI",
       desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery"
   }, {
       value: "sizzlejs",
       label: "Sizzle JS",
       desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine"
   }];

   $("#search").autocomplete({
           minLength: 0,
           source: projects,
           focus: function(event, ui) {
               console.log(ui.item.label);
               $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
               return false;
           },
           select: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
               $("#search").val(ui.item.label);
               $("#project-id").val(ui.item.value);
               $("#project-description").html(ui.item.desc);
               return false;
           }
       })
       .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
   });
```

And This function is not working at my end :

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

I want to show a another div and in this i want to show listing of data and when mouse over on this right hand another div and open this data.

Like this :

```
<div class="left_div">
<ul>
<li>Android</li>
<li>Java</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="right_div">
<p>Android is a mobile operating system (OS) currently developed by Google</p>
</div>
```